# How I can get amount of available free space in Hadoop in my database/schema?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, impala

How I can get amount of available free space in Hadoop in my database/schema? I can access both Hive or Impala, but I don't have administrative access to Hadoop (including HDFS). Also how I can check amount of already used space?

Comment: You can check in Hadoop Namenode Web UI for HDFS used and free space.

Comment: Hi Kumar!
Thanks for your reply.
Please can you tell me how I could access Hadoop Namenode Web UI? Just now I use Hue UI to access  Hadoop. Is that Hadoop Namenode Web UI  located inside Hue? Or it is somewhere outside? Should I ask admin to get access there?